# Suggestion for beginners of 3d measurement in images/videos?

Tags: computer-vision

I should face an application of estimating the size(lengths, width and height) of cars in surveillance videos. Where should I start to learn? And what is the baseline accuracy(%1? %10?) that the state-of-art could achieve?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a light subject to pick up, but if you are inclinded here is an excellent book to get you started: [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/)

Answer (score 2):

A very recent review of automated traffic analysis is this [one](http://www.mendeley.com/research/review-computer-vision-techniques-analysis-urban-traffic/). A slightly older one is [here](http://www.mendeley.com/research/computer-vision-techniques-traffic-flow-computation/).

In reality - this is a hard problem. Additional measurement of the vehicles in question will at the least require some form of calibration.